# Compare DateTime against current system time?

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I'm trying to make a C# method to fulfill this user story.

These are the 2 acceptance criteria

- Start time must be at least one hour later than the current system time.
- End time must be at last one hour after start time.

Both of the start and end time must be DateTime values, so I can parse it with the TryParse method.

Here's what I have in my code so far:

`

```
private DateTime datetime;
public DateTime datetimeStart { get; set; }
public DateTime datetimeEnd { get; set; }

while (true) {
    Util.GetInput("Delivery window start (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)");
    string userInput = ReadLine();
    
    if(DateTime.TryParse(userInput, out datetime))
    {
        if (datetime.TimeOfDay.Hours - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours >= 1) {
            datetimeStart = datetime;
        }
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        WriteLine("\tDelivery window start must be at least one hour in the future.");
    }
}

while (true) {
    Util.GetInput("Delivery window end (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)");
    string userInput = ReadLine();
    
    if(DateTime.TryParse(userInput, out datetime))
    {
        if (datetime.TimeOfDay.Hours - datetimeStart.TimeOfDay.Hours >= 1) {
            datetimeEnd = datetime;
        }
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        WriteLine("\tDelivery window end must be at least one hour later than the start.");
    }
}
```

`

I'm not fully sure how the DateTime type works yet, but later on, I'd need to get an output string with this format:
"The pickup window for your order will be 04:00 on 30/10/2022 and 20:00 on 30/10/2022", and just replace the data in the string with values from datetimeStart and datetimeEnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` provides all the tools to write your conditions in straightforward code:

> one hour later than / after `checkTime`

is just

```
checkTime.AddHours(1)
```

and

> `someTime` must be at least one hour later than / after `checkTime`

becomes

```
someTime >= checkTime.AddHours(1)
```

So your code may look something like this:

```
...........................
    if (datetime >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)) {
        datetimeStart = datetime;
    }
...........................
    if (datetime >= datetimeStart.AddHours(1)) {
        datetimeEnd = datetime;
    }
...........................
```

Answer (score 0):

A general rule of thumb is that any internal time keeping should be done in UTC, but when presenting in a UI (form or console) that you may show in local time.

Another rule is that when comparing `DateTime` objects that they should have the same `Kind`.

Perhaps add something like:

```
DateTime earliestStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
```

Later if you have a variable named `startTime` you want to make sure that it is greater than or equal to `earliestStartTime`.  Once you have `startTime` set, you can then have:

```
DateTime earliestEndTime = startTime.AddHours(1);
```

and likewise compare `endTime` to `earliestStartTime` for validity.

When presenting times to the user, you can use the `.ToLocalTime()` method.

Comment: "A general rule of thumb is that any internal time keeping should be done in UTC" - with significant caveats that should be understood... see my blog post about this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/

(Apologies if you're already aware, but "just store UTC" is too often treated as unthinking dogma...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough, and I have read that blog before (as well as almost everything you publish).  That's why I qualified my statement with *a general rule of thumb*.  The task at hand seems to require fairly simple time keeping and not repeated schedules crossing days, DST transitiions, or time zones.

Comment: It doesn't need to be repeated schedules or crossing different time zones: it looks like it's recording a future date/time (given the validation). That could be months in the future, and the time zone rules could change between now and then. It's possible that the delivery window is already expressed in UTC for other reasons - but if it's naturally expressed in local time, then doing the conversion to UTC *now* will make an assumption that the rules won't change before the delivery window actually occurs.